# How to delete extra audio track

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio, movie-clip-editor

I have video and audio in video sequence editor. Video is short and audio is long. How can i cut the audio to match the video.

[image]

Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: select an audio strip handle, then `G` and hold `CTRL` to snap it to the video. Then you can add keyframes to the audio strip's volume to make fades

Answer (score 0):

Blender hasn't extended audio capabilities:  you will have to render the audio of the portion you need (use PCM encoding, which is quality loseless) and then reimport the new audio data, or edit the file in another software (Free open source Audacity, Cubase, Logic or the professional Pro-Tools).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in Blender but it is a bit kludgy.

Determine where you want the audio to start and do a hard cut at that frame. Highlight the portion to the left and erase the strip.

Repeat the process for where you want the audio to end, highlighting the portion to the right and erasing it.

If you really want to do it right, use a program that will not only let you do the cuts, but that also has the ability to do a fade in and/or out.